# IBM Data Science Experience (DSX): How to connect with Client's ORACLE Database

Tags: r, oracle, data-science-experience

I'm able to connect with dashDB and to do that I've collected my credentials from Bluemix Manage. I've used ibmdbR package.

My client has ORACLE database. How can I make a connection to it. I like to use ibmdbR.

Comment: I don't think you can because `ibmdbR` is a Python package for Db2 databases. You can try one of the Oracle packages though, but I don't know if they will work.

Comment: @ptitzler As the name suggests `ibmdbR` is an R package hosted on CRAN https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ibmdbR/index.html . The Python counterpart is called `ibmdbpy`.